# Macro not showing result and no show error message to say what causes it

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to get data from another separate worksheet. I need to match the new and available model code in the Overall worksheet with the MASTER DATA existing worksheet to get the standard part name. However, I coded and run and no error prompt to me. there is no result too as the Standard part name column are still empty. Below are my code:

```
 Public Sub PopulatePart()

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 no_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 no_col = Range("A1", 
 Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Count

 Worksheets("Overall").Select
 For x = 1 To no_col
     If Cells(1, x).Value = "Spare Part Code 1" Or 
 Cells(1, x).Value = "SPARE PART CODE 1" Then
         codeCol = x
         Exit For
     End If
 Next x

 For x = 1 To no_col
     If Cells(1, x).Value = "Standard Part Name" Or 
 Cells(1, x).Value = "STANDARD PART NAME" Then
         nameCol = x
         Exit For
     End If
 Next x

 Worksheets("MASTER DATA").Select
 no_row_m = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For x = 1 To 200
     If Cells(1, x).Value = "Spare Part Code 1" Or 
 Cells(1, x).Value = "SPARE PART CODE 1" Then
         codemasCol = x
         Exit For
     End If
 Next x


 'Step 2 : Find Repair1 Column
 For x = 1 To 200
     If Cells(1, x).Value = "Standard Part Name" Or 
 Cells(1, x).Value = "STANDARD PART NAME" Then
         namemasCol = x
         Exit For
     End If
 Next x



 '---------------------------------------------------- 
---------------------
 'Populate All Data Based Part name Column and part 
 code Column

 InitProgressBar (no_row)
 For x = 2 To no_row
   DoEvents
   ShowProgress (x)
   Worksheets("Overall").Select
   Cells(x, codeCol).Select
   Cells(x, nameCol).Select
   initCode = Cells(x, codeCol).Value
   initName = Cells(x, nameCol).Value

   Worksheets("MASTER DATA").Select
   codeRow = Application.Match(initCode, 
 Range(Cells(1, codemasCol), Cells(no_row_m, 
 codemasCol)), 0)
   nameRow = Application.Match(initName, 
 Range(Cells(1, namemasCol), Cells(no_row_m, 
 namemasCol)), 0)

     If IsError(codeRow) = True Then
     Else
         stdCode = Cells(codeRow, codemasCol + 
 1).Value
          Worksheets("Overall").Select
         Cells(x, codeCol + 1) = stdCode
     End If

     Worksheets("MASTER DATA").Select

 If IsError(nameRow) = True Then
Else
    NameDes = Cells(nameRow, namemasCol + 1).Value
    Worksheets("Overall").Select
    Cells(x, nameCol + 1) = NameDes
End If

stdCode = ""
NameDes = ""

 Next x
 CloseProgressBar



 End Sub
```

Comment: Why not add print output of any intermediate results so you can see where it may stop?

Comment: I would first try to apply the advice from this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba   That will make your code more robust and easier to debug.